# <button> text disappears when using jQuery slideUp()/slideDown()

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, slideup, slidedown

I have 3 sections on a form which slideDown() when a checkbox is checked and slideUp() when the checkbox is unchecked.

In one part of the form i'm using a simple button to run a function.

If I uncheck the checkbox to slide the content up and then recheck it to slide the content back down again, the text in the button disappears and leaves me with a tiny button, which still works, but will not inform the user of what it does.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Richard

Comment: On every browser? Also you miss some words here and there in your question: ".. i'm using a simple XXXXX to run a function" and "...the text in the XXXXX disappears ..." . Seeing the code often helps.

Comment: would be easier to help you if you provide us some code.

Comment: I knew you guys would ask that :-).  Thanks for replying but i've managed to fix it and i'll add a wee answer.  Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so in my function to slide the content up I had the following line:

```
$("#" + section + " :input").val("");
```

It turns out that this not only clears the obvious fields, text etc, it also wipes out the button text.

I simply changed this line of code to:

```
$("#" + section + " :input[type='text']").val("");
```

Thanks for your prompt replies!

Richard